# Which Flink deleteMode to use in production?

Tags: apache-flink

Currently we're using the `Savepoint` deleteMode, which writes a savepoint on shutdown. Unfortunately sometimes Flink crash loops, i.e. when restarting it isn't able to write the savepoint so it repeatedly tries to restart. In this case we manually change the deleteMode to `None` and restart the application. Are savepoints recommended, or are checkpoints sufficient for Flink to self-recover? I don't think we've ever manually recovered from a savepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you arrange for the checkpoints to be retained, as in

```java
CheckpointConfig config = env.getCheckpointConfig();
config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(
  CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

then you can rely on them for restarts and rescaling. But for re-deployments that require state migration or a topology change, or if you are doing a Flink version upgrade, then savepoints are recommended.

The operational capabilities and guarantees of both checkpoints and savepoints are covered in more detail [in the Flink documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/state/checkpoints_vs_savepoints/).